# Select materialize doesn't show data angular

Tags: angular, laravel

I'm using the frameworks Laravel integrated with Angular and I'm work with APIS, so when request api to get data my select materialize doesn't show the data but in my .ts I have an console to see this data and its get data but in view not

my service.ts

```
getRoles() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.api}`)
        .toPromise();
        // .then( response => response.json());
}
```

now in my component.ts I have the following method

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.rService.getRoles()
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res)
          this.roles = res;
        })
}
```

so in my view the select

```
<select formControlName="role" [(ngModel)]="user.role">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha a função</option>
    <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [ngValue]="role.id">{{ role?.name }}</option> 
</select>
<label>Materialize Select</label>
```

but not have result, why ? 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure your data has an `id` property? The data you are logging to the console doesn't seem to have `id`, just `name` and `label`. Also you may need to share how you are creating reactive `FormControl` **role**. Also why convert it to a promise? Why not just `subscribe()` to the resulting `Observable<T>` of `get()`?

Comment: strange but my table has property ID and my formControl     ngOnInit() {
    this.getForm(); 
  }                          getForm() {
    this.administrator = this.formB.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required ],
      email: ['', Validators.required ],
      password: ['', Validators.required ],
      password_confirmation: ['', Validators.required ],
      role: ['', Validators.required ],
      cell: [''],
    })
  }

Comment: Are you sure you are sending it from your server? Add all this to the question so that others can help answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry friend the question about ID I forgot to add ID in controller laravel       $roles = DB::table('administrators')
                  ->select('id' ,'name', 'label')->get();

Comment: I tested in Postman the CRUD and its ok the only problem is in select materialize if I change and add <select formControlName="role" [(ngModel)]="user.role" class="browser-default"> its work but I dont want browser-default